# Groovy visualisation

Tags: groovy, uml

Background: I am a contractor and have taken ownership of several projects written in Groovy with Grails and Hibernate. The original developers are no longer available, there is no documentation. I am relatively new to Groovy. Eclipse is the mandated dev tool. I have many many years of Java.

Question: given the above what tools are available to help me understand the code? This is not supposed to be a Groovy vs Java argument but how do you cope with understanding the structure of the code when Eclipse cannot reliably generate things that I would expect to see in a Java environment e.g.

- call hierarchies
- class diagrams

Yes, I understand that the strengths of Groovy come at a price; but I am looking to experienced Groovy devs to share some light on the approach they would take to quickly understanding an existing Groovy project.

Comment: Everything is dynamic groovy? I mean, in eclipse, every method has an underline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a UML class diagram, you may want to look at the [Grails "Create Domain UML" plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/create-domain-uml).  Call hierarchies are likely only possible to determine by tracing running instances of your applications, due to the dynamic nature of groovy.  The [Grails profiler plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/profiler) will show you the call hierarchy at run time.